# Filtering by date in firestore(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firestore and am building an app that allows users to rent a bicycle. When a user rents a bicycle  they have to book it on a specific date.
I would like to perform a query that retrieves vehicles that have not been booked on a particular date. Say for instance a user selects the 28th of june, the results from the query should be vehicles which have not been booked on the 28th.

In firestore i save the booked dates as an array like so
[image]

So i tried to use this to get dates not in the array but it didn't seem to work.

```
List dates = [2021-08-05-25.12.00.000000];
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('bicycles')
.where('bookedDates',whereNotIn: dates)
.get()
```

I would appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to adapt your data model. You could have a document for each date in which you have a field of type Array that contains all the vehicles (bicycles?) IDs.

Each time a vehicle is booked for a given date, you remove the vehicle ID from the date document. You should do the booking with a [Transaction](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#transactions), in such a way you are sure that the update operation (removing the vehicle ID from the Array) only occurs using the latest data available on the server.

This way, it is very easy to query for the vehicles that are available for a given date.

---

You can initiate the date documents with a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). For example, you could create all the date documents of a month six months before this month starts. It all depends on your business case.

Comment: i think this carries potential

Answer (score 1):

That's query limitation. You'll have to combine two queries to achieve that behavior, something like this:

```dart
var s1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('bicycles')
    .where('bookedDates', isLessThan: '...28june...')
    .get();
  
var s2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('bicycles')
    .where('bookedDates', isGreaterThan: '...28june...')
    .get();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `bookedDates` is an array. It seems to me that you are trying to perform opposite of `array-contains` i.e. fetching documents where `bookedDates` does not contain any of the values in `dates`. As far as I know, there's no such operator.

Comment: True. It's for array comparison against a single field value.